# Empty page in html2pdf when using backtop in page tag

Tags: php, html2pdf

I am using html2pdf to generate PDF pages on the fly, every thing was working perfect as expected, however after I decided to show up page numbers and added backtop="7mm" attribute to the page tag it is display an empty page in most cases.

I am not sure what would be the best way to avoid this error, is there any thing wrong the way I am generating the PDF?

Here is the link of PDF that was generated. http://lovewithbug.com/downloads/mypdf.pdf

Link to the HTML letter that print $order->letter is generating http://lovewithbug.com/downloads/letter.html (ignore the different signature here)

The code that I am using to generate PDF is.

```
<page backtop="7mm">
<page_header>
    <div style="width:730px; text-align:right;"><?php echo $order->order_id;?> page [[page_cu]] of [[page_nb]]</div>
</page_header>
<div style="width:700px; margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px; padding:0;">     
    <table style="width:700px;" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>                   
                         <td style="width:250px;height:175px;" valign="top" align="left">
                         <?php echo $img_logo;?>
                         </td>
                        <td align="left" style="width:450px;font-size:16px; text-align:left;  padding-left:25px; " valign="middle"><strong>URGENT: PLEASE RESPOND IMMEDIATLEY</strong>   </td>
                    </tr>
    </table>
    <br style="height:1px;" />
   <table width="500" align="left" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="margin:37px 0 0 0; width:400px; padding:0;">

               <tr>
                 <td width="151"  valign="top" style="font-size:16px; width:127px; vertical-align:top; text-align:left; text-transform:uppercase;">
                 <div style="text-align:center;">
                 <strong>
                 CONFIDENTAIL<br />
                 <?php echo date("F d"); ?><br />
                 <?php echo date("Y");?>
                 </strong>
                 </div>
                 </td>  
                 <td width="247"  align="left" valign="top" style="font-size:13px; text-align:left; margin:0 0 0 10px;">
                    <?php  echo (!empty($order->customer))?$order->customer.'<br />':''; ?>
                    <?php  echo (!empty($order->stress_address))?$order->stress_address.'<br />':''; ?>
                    <?php  echo (!empty($order->unit))?$order->unit.'<br />':''; ?>
                    <?php  echo (!empty($order->town))?$order->town.' ':''; ?>
                    <?php echo (!empty($order->state))?$order->state.' ':''; ?>
                    <?php  echo (!empty($order->zip_code))?$order->zip_code.'<br />':''; ?>
                 </td>
               </tr>                                                          
   </table>


  <div style="margin:70px 0 0 0;"> <div style="background-color:#000; width:700px; height:1px;" ></div> </div> 
  <?php  print ($order->letter); ?>   
   </div>        
  </page>
```

Comment: Try adding `<?php ob_start(); ?>` at the top of your code, see if this helps. [**Consult this reference I found-LINK**](http://wiki.spipu.net/doku.php?id=html2pdf:en:v3:marges) and look through for more ideas.

Comment: So, any luck with my suggestion?

Comment: Fred, thank you for your suggestion, but `<?php ob_start(); ?>` doesn't seem to do the trick.

Comment: You're welcome. Sorry I couldn't find anything else on the subject. Strange indeed. Good luck in finding a solution Patri, *cheers.*

Comment: It was because of 

    `<div style="width:700px; margin-left:30px; margin-right:30px; padding:0;">`   

Margins in the above div, I have removed them and used the margins provided by html2pdf as showen below, hope it may help somebody.

    `<page backleft="10mm" backtop="10mm" backright="10mm" backbottom="10mm">`

Comment: You can make it as an answer Patri, glad you found the problem.